# dired, zip as a directory

Tags: dired, tramp, compression

With archivemount, one can mount a zip file. Is there any way to treat a zip file just like a directory in dired?

The we wouldn't have to unzip the archive, which takes time and you probably need to clean up as well. Another alternative is mounting, but it takes up a mount point and you have to deal with clean ups.

A transparent mount would solve this, just like in HURD;)

Answer (score 1):

This is built-in for some systems.  Refer to:

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(tramp)Archive file names`

> TRAMP offers also transparent access to files inside file archives.
> This is possible only on hosts which have installed GVFS (the GNOME
> Virtual File System), *note GVFS-based methods::.  Internally, file
> archives are mounted via the GVFS ‘archive’ method.

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVFS

Obviously this isn't a regular filesystem, and so you can't do
everything you could normally do in dired.

YMMV.

Comment: In short, if you want to see `/path/to/file.zip` in dired, open it like `C-x d /path/to/file.zip/` in Emacs - note the trailing slash. This works on Linux only.